# Is there any way to use traffic layer in bing maps silverlight sdk?

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, traffic

I tried with Bing maps, Silverlight and wpf sdk and I couldnt't find something related to traffic layer.

The problem is that when I use the Bing maps for matrostyle app sdk, it is very easy to enable traffic layer:

```
myMap.showTraffic=true;
```

If there is a business restriction, I think it is not possible to use traffic layer from metrostyle app component too.

Comment: Is this a question, or a statement? Most questions would have a question mark somewhere at least? :)

Comment: yess sure this is a question :) just I commented my question. Is there any way to use traffic layer in bing maps silverlight sdk???

Answer (score 0):

The WPF SDK for Bing Maps does not allow you to include the traffic layer.  This is due to licensing restrictions and the need for the traffic data to be public.  The issue is explained in this forum post on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols/thread/3e75890d-d2e4-4a5c-b186-347322d3c3df

You can add a traffic layer to the Silverlight SDK, though.  Which is explained in this post:

[Traffic Layer for Bing Maps in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529781/traffic-layer-for-bing-maps-in-silverlight)